# Can a class have multiple thread function?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I wrote a class that can do some work in another thread:

```
    class SkeData
    {
    public:
        SkeData(INuiSensor* pSensor);
        ~SkeData();
        HANDLE StartSaveSkeData_Frames(int nFrames = 1);
        HANDLE StartSaveSkeData2File_Frames(HANDLE hFile,int nFrames = 1);
            [...]

    private:
          //Two thread functions
        static DWORD WINAPI AddFrames(LPVOID lpParam);
        static DWORD WINAPI AddFrames2File(LPVOID lpParam);
            [...]
    };

    HANDLE SkeData::StartSaveSkeData_Frames(int nFrames)
    {
        [...]
        m_hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, AddFrames, this, 0, NULL);
        return m_hThread;
    }

    HANDLE SkeData::StartSaveSkeData2File_Frames(HANDLE hFile,int nFrames)
    {
        [...]
        m_hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, AddFrames2File, this, 0, NULL);
        return m_hThread;
    }

    DWORD WINAPI SkeData::AddFrames(LPVOID lpParam)
    {
        SkeData *This = (SkeData *)lpParam;
        return This->Thread_AddFrames();
    }

    DWORD WINAPI SkeData::AddFrames2File(LPVOID lpParam)
    {
        SkeData *This = (SkeData *)lpParam;
        return This->Thread_AddFrames2File();
    }



When I built the program solution in VS2010, linking error came up like this:
SkeData.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: unsigned long __thiscall SkeData::Thread_AddFrames2File(void)" (?Thread_AddFrames2File@SkeData@@AAEKXZ) referenced in function "private: static unsigned long __stdcall SkeData::AddFrames2File(void *)" (?AddFrames2File@SkeData@@CGKPAX@Z)
1>E:\***\DataCollection.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

However, when I removed one of the thread functions, it can be successfully built. Thus I guess the reason to the error is something about the thread function. But I still don't understand why I can not add one more thread function in my class???

I hope anyone can give more explanations.

Thank you!

More: Sorry there's something wrong when I pasted my code..I did implement both of the thread functions...And if I didn't, the error will not be like this ,right?

Comment: Because you never *added* one more thread function; You *claimed* you did by adding the prototype member to the class *declaration*, but you never *implemented* it (at least that you have shown here).

Comment: Did you read the error message? What made you think that the linker error has to do with multithreading?

Comment: @stakx:Of course I read the error message..The reason I thought it's about multithreading is because when I removed one of the thread functions, it can be successfully built.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the linking error, you probably never defined the function `AddFrames2File`. Since you are using the function, the linker (basically the part of the compiler that's responsible for bringing all your code together) will complain that it can't find a definition of this function.

The declaration of a function is declaring it's prototype. That is, it's return type, name and parameters, like you did in your class declaration.

```
static DWORD WINAPI AddFrames2File(LPVOID lpParam); //lpParam can be ommited
```

From now on, you can use this function because your compiler knows how it should be called. (Note that `lpParam` can be ommited, it is not required for your compiler to know how the function can be called) However, you still need to *define* your function somewhere to actually associate code with the function. Like so:

```
static DWORD WINAPI SkeData::AddFrames2File(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    //Actual code here
    std::cout << "This function is now defined!" << std::endl;
}
```

Note that I'm using `SkeData::` to tell the compiler what function I'm defining. If I didn't do this, the function definition would be taken as defining a new function in the global namespace (or whatever namespace you currently happen to be working in).